# Webscraping & beautifulsoup - sorting extracted odds and bet-text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape this [website](https://www.cashpoint.dk/da/?r=bets/xtra&group=464289&game=312011177), it's a bookmaker called matchpoint.com. My goal is to have a spreadsheet where I can see the odds without having to visit their site.

My code prints the odds and the bet-text. But it doesn't sort the odds so it matches the bet-text. I've attached a picture below where you can see the page I'm scraping. For the first bet-text there are three odds and for another there are two odds attached to the text. I spent 3 days searching through stackoverflow and I haven't been able to move on from here.

**In:**

```
"""
Soccer match results scraping object.
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

class scraper():

    def __init__(self):

        print('__init__ called')

    def parsedata(self):

        self.url = "https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/?r=bets/xtra&group=461392&game=312004790"
        self.res = requests.get(self.url)                                    
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.res.text, "lxml")                     
        self.table = self.soup.find_all("table", class_="sportbet_extra_list_table")

        for self.items in self.table:

            self.odds = self.items.find("div", class_="sportbet_content_rate_right").get_text().strip()
            print(self.odds) 

            self.text = self.items.find("td", class_="sportbet_extra_c1").get_text().strip()
            print(self.text) 

Scrape = scraper()
Scrape.parsedata()
```

**Out:**

```
__init__ called
1,38
Hvem vinder kampen?
1,09
Dobbeltchance
1,12
Head to Head (penge tilbage ved uafgjort)
2,17
Handicap 0:1
4,25
Handicap 0:2
8,60

etc
```

[The website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Wca.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"""
Soccer match results scraping object.
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://www.cashpoint.dk/da/?r=bets/xtra&group=467265&game=312021291"


class scraper():

    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__ called')

        self.gamesList = []

    def Cashpoint(self, url):

        self.r = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.r.text, "lxml")

        self.content = self.soup.find_all("div", class_="sportbet_extra_content")

        for self.getTable in self.content:
            self.oneTable = self.getTable.find_all("table", class_="sportbet_extra_list_table")

        self.btextCount = len(self.oneTable)  # Amount of tables

        with open('names.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            headers = ['btext']
            writer.writerow(headers)

            for x in range(self.btextCount):  # Bettext count.

                # One Bettext, three odds per loop.

                # Bettext
                self.rawText = self.oneTable[x].find_all("td", class_="sportbet_extra_c1")

                for self.getText in self.rawText:
                    self.getme = self.getText.get_text().strip().split('  ')[0]
                    self.txtList = [self.getme]
                    print(self.txtList)

                # Odds
                self.oddsTable = self.oneTable[x].find_all("div", class_="sportbet_content_rate_right")
                for self.oddsRaw in self.oddsTable:
                    self.odds = self.oddsRaw.get_text().strip()
                    self.newodds = [self.odds]
                    print(self.newodds)


        d = {'Bettext': [2, 52123321], 'Odds': [3, 4]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        print(df)


                    # print(self.gamesList)


            # csvfile.close()
            # print("CSVFILE CLOSED")


scrape = scraper()
scrape.Cashpoint(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try using `find_all` to extract all the odds instead of `find`.

```
all_odds = self.items.find_all("div", class_="sportbet_content_rate_right").get_text().strip()
self.odds = [x.get_text().strip() for x in all_odds]
print(self.odds)
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to attach the bettext to the odds, I have no problem extracting the odds. Another thing, you cannot strip nor get_text while using find_all

Comment: you can strip or get_text using find_all but you need to iterate over each element in the result of find_all .